# Check if product has custom options Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, if

I want to **display some text** next to the price of a product **if it has custom options**. I have placed some code in `final_price.phtml` but it doesn't show the message on custom option products.

Can anyone please advise an update to the below to get this working?

```
<span class="special-price">
    /** Show text if has custom option */ <?php if ($block->hasOptions()):?>
        <?php echo ('from'); ?>
    <?php endif;?> /** Show text if has custom option */
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
</span>
```

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/check-product-has-options-in-magento-2/ check all type of product example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you try sth like

```
$block->getSaleableItem()->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($block->getSaleableItem());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code -

```
$customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);

if(count($customOptions) > 0){
  //The product has custom options
}
```

Reference:
https://www.mageplaza.com/how-to-get-product-options-in-magento-2.html